# how much does 'Danger Close' Perk affect?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

The danger close perk is much like the perk in other installments of the series, increases explosive damage.

My question is does it affect *all* explosions or simply ones from grenades/launchers.

Example, (and my main question) does it affect the NA-45's special effect? How about things that aren't controlled by you, like streak rewards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the official information, so I'm going to give you my opinion and that of a trusted youtuber : I think it affects all of explosions that you cause directly (grenades, launchers, NA-45 but not killstreak bonuses, like planes or assault drones even controlled ones).

For the NA-45, I didn't test it but youtuber Drift0r who usually tests everything advices to use it ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BsUpTaUqiU)).

Answer (score 0):

It does say in the perk description (in game) that it increases the effects of explosions and scorestreaks. I've heard that it increases the damage of explosions by 10%, I would expect that it does the same with damage dealt by scorestreaks.